# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 Downloads

Tags: disk-usage

How do I fix The following: The upgrade needs a total of 76.2 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 76.2 M of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.

Comment: I've tried numerous suggestions but to no avail.

Comment: [Removing old kernels](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot), as [Avinash Raj suggested](http://askubuntu.com/a/433514/22949), hasn't worked? Can you provide details about what you did, whether or not you were able to remove any old kernels, how many you removed, how much if any space was freed, etc.? Alternatively, if you're having trouble removing old kernels or if you're worried about making sure not to remove the kernel the system currently depends on--which is a reasonable concern, you should not uninstall that one!--please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

From the error report, it clearly says that you have to free up some space around 80 MB on your `/boot` partition or you have to increase the size of `/boot` partition.

Mainly `/boot` partition contains old(unused) kernals.Removing all of them will give you some space.See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) question for how to free up some space in your `/boot` partition.

If you want to increase the size of `/boot` partition, then you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk or gparted live disk.Freeup some space from other partition and add it to your `/boot` partition.